# What's the optimum size for a class file?

Tags: class, size

I know that there is no single "ideal" size of a class file, but still...

Are there any data (like studies, not like opinion) on what is the optimum size for a class file?

Comment: Probable duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651346/what-is-the-limit-n-of-maximum-methods-you-allow-in-your-classes/

Comment: I *know* this is duped *somewhere*...

Comment: It might different depending on what you are trying to optimize: startup speed, running speed, readability, re-usability.

Comment: Since a kitbag question is the name given in the Israeli army to any useless question, why tag it as such

Answer (score 8):

I'd say the optimum size would be enough code for the class to do its job.

Answer (score 4):

Opinion: The smallest possible size that does the job, while maintaining readability  but promoting brevity.

In [academia](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=567176.567181) there is some work on the subject to try and be more formal.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't care about the size of the class file, but about the size of the source file.

Usually the class file size is roughly a function of the source file size, but that's no reason to observe the size of the class file.